# Feedback on vote up/down button

Tags: support, feature-request

I didn't find any feedback section on Stackoverflow, hence writing my feedback here.

I find Vote up/down buttons very confusing. Many times they get clicked by mistake and there is no option to undo that.

I don't want to downvote anything just by mistake. I would suggest a confirmation before finalizing up or down vote.

If I am missing something here, I request for the information on the same. Thanks.

Comment: you can click same arrow again and it acts as undo. But I not sure is this working after page refresh or logout and login scenario but yes this is solution for your question

Comment: @Guru Votes get locked in after 15 (if I recall correctly) minutes, unless the post is subsequently edited.

Comment: Yes, this is what happened. I came to know about this accidental vote after sometime. On hover it showed tooltip 'click again to undo'. But on click it said 'you have voted 56 minutes ago, your vote is locked'.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ohh Thanks but why stack locked it after some time? suppose I read the ans and I like it. I up-voted it and after 2-3 days I realize this is not useful answer or there is a even better way there must be way to degrade / undo again

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: votes are locked after an unspecified time to minimise gaming, but the time is always < 5 minutes.

Comment: @Guru: votes are unlocked again if a post is edited.

Comment: If you get confused by the up/down arrows many times then maybe you should just stay away from them? There you go - problem solved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can click the corresponding arrow again to undo the action. That's made clear in the hover tooltip, *but only after you've actually performed the action*. If you already read the tooltip prior to taking the action, you might not think to read it again because there's no reason to expect it to change.

I don't think that a confirmation would be helpful, and might just act as another barrier to actually casting votes - something we want to encourage, not discourage.

If I was going to propose a change, it would be this: The tooltip should include "(click again to undo)" at the end all of the time, so that no matter what state it's in when you read that text it's clear how you go about reverting the action.

Comment: What is the time limit for undoing your vote?

Answer (score 7):

You can simply undo a vote by clicking the same button again.

A *"Are you sure?"* confirmation for every vote seems like a major pain to deal with, discouraging people to vote.